# How do I change the SDK app engine on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am pretty new to coding. I help run a small charity and a friend of a friend set up a website for us which I have been running for the last few years. I have managed to sort things out with a lot of copy and pasting and trial and error but I have now hit a wall.
I could not deploy to the server so I went back and reinstalled everything. I got further with the process this time but then it told me to update the SDK. I downloaded the newest SDK but cannot add this to my project in eclipse.
I have learned a lot over the years but I am still pretty dense when it comes to certain things. [Find error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3bS8.jpg)
If anyone can help and explain it in laymen terms I'd appreciate it.
Many Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with App Engine, but noticed this:
https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find information about how to manage the Cloud SDK in Cloud Tools for Eclipse.

> You can either allow Cloud Tools for Eclipse to download and install
>   an SDK for you, or you can point it to a specific SDK you've installed
>   outside of Eclipse.

[Managing the SDK for Your Project](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/manage-sdk)